# launchctl print system printed "bootcache hack" and "exec hack" results

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, launchctl

I used the following command to list launchctl facilities, and at the very end of the print out were some interesting results:

command used:

```
launchctl print system
```

end of results:

```
    properties = {
        shutting down = 0
        slain = 0
        uncorked = 0
        origin resolved = 0
        deactivated = 0
        inactive = 0
        initial on-demand = 1
        audit check done = 1
        bootcache hack = 1
        cocooning = 0
        gui = 0
        gui login = 0
        exec hack = 0
    }
}
```

Assuming these are not normal, what do they mean, and what's my next step? I can print the full results if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These results are normal. A brand new OS X install with absolutely no third-party software installed and has never connected to a network contains the same properties.

Don't read `hack` as a portent of some malicious attack. The term is *frequently* (and in this case *likely*) used to mean `fix` or `band-aid` and was undoubtedly condoned or even implemented by Apple.